# I need to create a program that inputs a list of strings, and output the number of integers, floats and others there are

Tags: python, python-3.x

So my problem is: user inputs a list of strings and I need to find the frequencies of integers, floats and others that appear in the list this is my attempt

```
str_s = "1,2.3, 4.3,str"
s = str_s.split(",")

int_s =[]
float_s=[]
other_s=[]


for i in s:
try:
    int(s[i])
    int_s.append(s[i])
except ValueError:
    pass
    try:
        float(s[i])
        float_s.append(s[i])
    except ValueError:
        other_s.append(s[i])
```

So I think my problem is taking elements of a list that is a string and checking to see if its an integer or float, I've tried this but it crashes the program

```
def load_list_of_strings():
"""
user enters a list of strings as a string with ',' between and the function returns 
these strings as a list
"""
import ast
string=input("""Enter your strings with a "," between each:""")
if string=="":
     return []
string=ast.literal_eval(string)
string = [n.strip() for n in string]

return string
```

Comment: What error do you get? Can you be more specific about the input format and the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str_s = "1,2.3, 4.3,str"
s = str_s.split(",")

int_s =[]
float_s=[]
other_s=[]


for i in s:
    try:
        int_s.append(int(i))
    except ValueError:
        try:
            float_s.append(float(i))
        except ValueError:
            other_s.append(i)

print int_s
print float_s
print other_s
```

The issue is you tried accessing elements of your lists like:
s[i].
The issue with this is i can be "1", "2.3", "4.3", or "str". All of which are not valid. The only valid indexes in this example are: s[0] s[1] s[2] s[3]

Comment: OP specified tag `python3`, just add the parenthesis for the `print` commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use regular expressions (allowing spaces before after numbers)

```
import re
RE_FLOAT = re.compile(r"^\s*(\d+\.\d*)|(\d*\.\d+)\s*$")
RE_INT = re.compile(r"^\s*\d+\s*$")

str_s = "1,2.3, 4.3 ,.123,450.,str,A123,1001D".split(",")
int_s = []
float_s = []
other_s = []
for i in str_s:
  if RE_FLOAT.match(i):
    float_s.append(i)
  elif RE_INT.match(i):
    int_s.append(i)
  else:
    other_s.append(i)

print (int_s)
print (float_s)
print (other_s)
```